# Installing a Minimal qgis, without extensions (GRASS, SAGA)?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

Is it somehow possible to install QGIS without the GRASS and SAGA extensions?

I just want to have a small software package to create and export some simple maps and my hdd is quite full already.

I really won't need these extensions but the software package of qgis.com includes all.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Its Windows 7 (32 Bit)
Sorry, I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 7):

In the OSGeo4W installer, there is an **advanced install** option which allows you to chose exactly what should be installed. The other installers will just install everything.